# React Native [Network error]: TypeError: Network request failed using Apollo Client

Tags: react-native, expo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I just want to get connected on my Apollo Server on localhost using React Native with Expo.

If I try to use the following api link `https://q815p14lp.lp.gql.zone/graphql` its working fine. But if I try to use `http://127.0.0.1:8080/graphql` or `http://localhost:8080/graphql` I get the following error: `[Network error]: TypeError: Network request failed`

This is my code where I try to get connected.

```
const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/graphql' });

const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
  const token = await getToken();

  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : null,
    }
  };
});

const errorLink = onError(({ networkError, graphQLErrors }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors)
    graphQLErrors.map(({ message, locations, path }) =>
      console.log(
        `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`
      )
    );
  if (networkError) console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([errorLink, authLink, httpLink]),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

"apollo-boost": "^0.1.18",
"apollo-link-context": "^1.0.9",
"apollo-link-error": "^1.1.1",
"expo": "^30.0.1",
"react-apollo": "^2.2.4",
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The host `*.lp.gql.zone` is a Launchpad graphql server. So you have your server running on Launchpad, not on your local machine.

Also connecting to your local machine using Expo does not make a lot of sense. The "localhost" in this case is the phone device that runs the app.

I guess what you really want is for the Expo app on the device to connect to your development graphql server on your mac/pc? In this case you should use the IP address you see in the debug view:

[image]

Your connect url in this case becomes: `http://10.10.9.70:8080/graphql`

Comment: Incredible! Lost 4 hours on this. A million thanks @Jesper!! <3